# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working on Android 7.0

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova geolocation plugin to get user current position in IBM MobileFirst Hybrid Application,I am able to get locations on all Android devices except Android 7.0

On Android 7.0 getting error code as 2 and message is 'application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions'.
Here is my code and permissions which I have added androidManifest file

```
 JAVAScript Code:
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(position));
     },function(error){
        alert("error "+error.code+" "+error.message);
 },{enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout:10000});

 Android permissions:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: If you go into setting ->applications ->  your application -> permissions and enable locations , does it work?

Comment: @Vivin K-yes,working.

Comment: This is expected because Android has increased the default security settings

Answer (score 0):

What you see is not an MFP issue at all. This is from the permission system introduced in Android starting 6.0 onwards.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en

To get your geolocation working , do this:

Go into `

> Settings -> Applications -> Your application -> Permissions and Enable
>   Locations (toggle switch).

This should get you going.

Comment: Thanks vivin k,but does it correct way to ask every user to follow same,even I am worrying about how to convince client.

Comment: @Swamy That is how the Android ecosystem works. May be you should get in touch with folks at Android/Google for a better way to convince clients.